# Random generator based off NStimer Xcode 7 swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, random, timer

I want a function to be called at random times while the user is playing. For example after 2 seconds passed a function is called and then after another 6 seconds it is called again. How do I do that?

This is not working

```
    func time() {
randomNumber = CGFloat((drand48())
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(randomNumber, traget: self, selector: "startTimer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Xcode is not liking it and I donot know why

Comment: Update your question with what you tried and explain what the exact issues are.

Comment: Ok. I just did it now

Comment: Where? I don't see any code in your question. We are not here to do your work for you. Try something. When you get stuck, update your question with your relevant code and explain what issues you are having.

Comment: Ok. I struglling so much but ill so you what I have

Comment: @rmaddy I got nothing I had nstimers and arrrandombut it did work

Comment: "but it did work". You mean "but it did not work?" Ok, post the code that you tried. We'll help you debug it.

Comment: `Xcode is not liking it` what doesn't it like? Does it not compile? Does it throw a runtime error? Does the app freeze? Giving specifics will help others help you.

Comment: Unless you can describe the problem clearly we can't help you. I have a guess, but you aren't explaining your problem well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. This is not a site where you get other people to write your code for you. It's a site to ask for help with code you write yourself.

You want to use `arc4random_uniform()` to create a random number, and then `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` to fire your timer at a random time in the future.

Try that, and if you have problems, update your question with the code you're trying and tell us what happens with it.

### Edit:

Here's a suggestion: log a few values of randomNumber. Are they small values? Those are a delay in seconds. If you are getting values of 1000, 1,000,000, or greater, it's going to take a **while** for your timer to fire.

Comment: ok ill try thats im new to stack overflow

Comment: I adding some new info @Duncan C